# How to pass multiple variable through url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, syntax-error

ME use the following syntax for passing values through url but for one value it gives correct result but for second it gives error.

for one value its correct

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("IndexController/SingleProperty?id=".$val["UserID"]);?>" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" />View Details</a>
```

when me add second value it gives the error

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("IndexController/SingleProperty?id=".$val["HouseID"]&"id2=".$val["UserID"]);?>" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" />View Details</a>
```

it gives the error..
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your string, because you are not using `.` correctly, You can do it like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("IndexController/SingleProperty?id=".$val["HouseID"]."&id2=".$val["UserID"]);?>" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" />View Details</a>
```

Comment: ishfaq - in PHP whenever you are passing strings inside html tag, First echo that string and then use it, that will help you